# sed: match a group of digits before a word

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to extract the numbers from lines like:

```
<foo> 34Kb data <foo>
<foo> 2Kb data <foo>
```

where I am also extracting other parameters, so it is important to match the group of numbers before `Kb data` and to preferably use `sed`.

I have tried:

```
sed -r 's/.*([0-9]+)Kb data.*/\1/'
```

And other combinations, but they only gave me the last digit for a group of digits.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
sed -r 's/.*\b([0-9]+).*/\1/'
```

`\b` matches a word boundary (beginning or end of a word).

Answer (score 3):

This is because of your `*` greedy operator.But sed does not support `*?`  non greedy operator.so instead use `grep -P`

```
grep -P '.*?([0-9]+)Kb data.*'
```

or

```
grep -P '\d+(?=Kb)'
```

simply.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/oL9kE8/13

Or

```
sed -r 's/[^0-9]*([0-9]+)Kb data.*/\1/'
```

Comment: I would like to use `sed` for it as this is only a small part of many other parameters that I am already extracting for the line. Thank you for the answer though!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
awk -F"[^0-9]" '{$1=$1}1' file
      34
      2
```